# How to target particular div layer to display different content

Tags: jquery, css, html, layer

I'm new to css, jquery and layers.

I need to build some page that has 3 links that need to show some content.
When clicking on lin1 1, I need to show content1.html.
The same is with link 2 and 3 for content2.html and content3.html accordingly.

The content layer will need to be refreshed with new info.

How can I do it? Please help.

Comment: First thing you have to do is start writing your code

Comment: Here's how to do it fast, pick up the phone, call a developer! If that's not what you want, learn HTML, CSS and javascript, and this should be a breeze.

Comment: Thak's for an advice. I already built 3 pages. What I need is to know how to show their content in a certain part of a page when clicking the link

Comment: Well if I understand you correct you have Build 3 Different sites? and want to display them at one site?. its very unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: I built 3 pages. Now I need to display their content in a targeted container.

Comment: I'd love to see the 3 sites you built, that would be fun!

Comment: I do not see anything funny. Just trying to learn what I did not work with before in a very short period of time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way you can do it with jquery.

HTML CODE:

```
<button id="btn1">Content 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Content 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Content 3</button>

<div id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content2">Content 2</div>
<div id="content3">Content 3</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
div{
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
$("#content1").show();
$("#content2").hide();
$("#content3").hide();
});
 $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#content1").hide();
    $("#content2").show();
    $("#content3").hide();
});
$("#btn3").click(function(){
$("#content1").hide();
    $("#content2").hide();
    $("#content3").show();
});
});
```

If you want to see it just check this out [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cR97F/2/)

Comment: Here is the answer to your private message to me. 

change your css to: 
.content div{
    display: none;
}